# Hotel quarantine in France

Tags: france, covid-19, quarantine, lyon

I am travelling to Lyon from India via Paris and as per the current guidelines I need to quarantine myself for 10 days.

Since I do not have a permanent residence there yet, I need to quarantine in some hotel.

1. Please let me know if I can quarantine in any hotel? In case, there are some special (government prescribed) hotels where one must quarantine, any pointer to the names of those hotels would be helpful.
2. Can I take a train from Paris to Lyon on the same day as I arrive at Paris (without quarantine)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can quarantine in a hotel of your choosing and the government does not seem to recommend any. This is not a government-managed quarantine programme like there is in Australia or New Zealand but an obligation to provide some information to the authorities, who can then theoretically check whether you are effectively present where you say you would be.

The way the rules are phrased, it's implied that French residents can return to their home and that you are responsible for finding a hotel so taking the train is presumably allowed. Concretely, you are supposed to present the exact address / proof of a booking before boarding and once again after arriving. At the same time, government sites mention the possibility to get assistance through a *cellule territoriale d’appui à l’isolement* if you don't have a place to quarantine.

Note that you are also allowed to go out of your place of quarantine every day for two hours, between 10 and 12.

Comment: Could you please guide me to the website where these rules are written? I would track it for any changes made by the French government.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to the [official diplomatic website](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/coronavirus-advice-for-foreign-nationals-in-france/), section

> Arrivals from Argentina, Bangladesh, Brazil, Chile, India, Nepal, Pakistan, Qatar, South Africa, Sri Lanka, Turkey and the United Arab Emirates; and from 16 May, Bahrein, Colombia, Costa Rica and Uruguay

You can choose where you want to quarentine, be it a home or a hotel...
But be sure to fill the correct forms to be allowed in